# PHP ComboBox display selected value on other page

Tags: php, combobox

I want to show the selected value from a combobox that is on one page, and then show it on other page, and it worked with this code:

**Code on page1:**

```
<form action = 'enviar.php' method = "POST">

<select required id = "cmbAno" name = "Make">

<option value="ano_1"> 1º </option>
<option value="ano_2"> 2º </option>
<option value="ano_3"> 3º </option>
<option value="ano_4"> 4º </option>
<option value="ano_5"> 5º </option>
<option value="ano_6"> 6º </option>
<option value="ano_7"> 7º </option>
<option value="ano_8"> 8º </option>
<option value="ano_9"> 9º </option>
<option value="ano_10"> 10º </option>
<option value="ano_11"> 11º </option>
<option value="ano_12"> 12º </option>

</select>

<script>
        function run() 
        {
            document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("cmbAno").value;
        }

        function up() 
        {
            var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        }
</script>
```

**Code on page2:**

```
<?php

  echo $_POST['Make'];
```

?>

**And instead of show the selected option like '1º' it shows the option value 'ano_1'**

Answer (score 0):

You could take the value and re-translate it to the desired text. Something like the snippet below. With 12 options it will get pretty large, however.

```
<?php if($_POST['Make'] == "ano_1"){ $result = "1º"; }elseif{ ...Continue... } ?>
```

And then later - where you want to display the result:

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```

This should do what you want. There may be a more efficient way - but I'm still a php rookie.